# Segoe Symbol UI in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, fonts, microsoft-metro

I have a very strange behavior in an application that is targeted to Windows Phone 7.1 (and therefor will also run on Windows Phone 8).

For my icons I'm using the Segoe UI Symbol font. 
When I run the application on WP 8, the icons are displayed correctly.
If I run it in WP7 though, some of the icons are displayed as rectangles.

I figured that the font on WP7 was probably an older version, so what I did was download the font from my Win8 PC and used it as an embedded font in WP7, but it still does not work.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: How do you reference the font in the XAML?

Comment: First I simply referenced the font by name: "Segoe UI Symbol".When I embedded the font I did it like this: ".\Font\Symbol.ttf#Segoe UI Symbol" where the first part is the path to the ttf and the second part the name of the font

Comment: Hmm, I also tried renaming the file and the font family name (using TypoGraf), but it still doesn't work. Strangely enough, in VS designer and in Blend the icons are displayed correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you reference it as "Resource"?
Try specify full path with assembly name. Like

```
/Acme.Product;component/Assets/seguisym.ttf#Segoe UI Symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

I managed to get it working.
What I needed to do was:

- Clean the font
- Rename the original file name
- Rename the font using TypoGraf
- Rebuild the project

I'm not a 100% sure that everything is needed but at least this way I got it working.

Comment: Trying to solve the same issue.. I've done all the steps here except "Clean the font". What exactly does that mean?